# Confusion: @Override cannot be converted to Annotation in java?

Tags: java

I am trying to test the **@Override** annotation in java. First, I overload the **`overloadedMethod`** in the **`Overload`** class, with and without parameter.

```
public class Overload {

    //overloaded method with and without param
    public void overloadedMethod(){
        System.out.println("overloadedMethod(): No parameter");
    }

    public void overloadedMethod(String s){
        System.out.println("overloadedMethod(): String");
    }

}
```

Then **`Override`** is a sub-class of the **`Overload`** class. I try to override one of the **`overloadedMethod`**. The **`@Override`** annotation is added to make sure this method is correctly override.

```
public class Override extends Overload{

    //now I want to override
    @Override
    public void overloadedMethod(String s){
        System.out.println("overloadedMethod(): String is overrided");
    }

    /**
     *  MAIN
     *  @param args void
     */
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Override myOverride=new Override();
        //test
        myOverride.overloadedMethod();
        myOverride.overloadedMethod("Hello");
    }
}
```

But an error occurred: **Override cannot be converted to Annotation**

```
/Users/Wei/java/com/ciaoshen/thinkinjava/chapter7/Override.java:20: error: incompatible types: Override cannot be converted to Annotation
    @Override
     ^
1 error
```

Anyone can tell me what's the problem here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The compiler thinks you try to use your class as an annotation.

Annotations share the same namespace as classes. That's why you import them with the same statements you use for importing classes. As you now have a class with the same name in the current package this class is preferred over the annotation from a different package.

You may use the annotation by its full name:

```
@java.lang.Override
public void overloadedMethod(String s){
    System.out.println("overloadedMethod(): String is overrided");
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Don't call the class Override or use the complete name with package :

```
@java.lang.Override
```

Answer (score 2):

The annotation Override is defined as

```
@interface Override {
....
```

and you have defined a class named `Override` too...

this is generating conflicts in the compiler because one name is related to 2 different things in the project...

rename your class to something different like MyOverride or use for the annotation the full name of the annotation.

```
@java.lang.Override
 public void overloadedMethod(String s){...
```